# Random effect nested within fixed effect in mixed model in R

Tags: mixed-model, random-effects-model, biostatistics, nested-models

I am trying to respond to a reviewers assessment of my data analysis for a peer reviewed journal.

I sampled fish abundance at 4 sites Inside a reserve and 4 sites outside of a Reserve ('Reserve' has 2 levels: Inside/Outside). Within each of those levels, Sites can also be classified by their Proximity to a nearby fishery ('Proximity' 2 levels: Near/Far). I am interested in the effect of the Reserve, Proximity and their interaction on fish abundance. All sites were sampled 6 times over the course of a year ('Time' has 6 levels).

This is the comment from the reviewer 
"Reserve and Proximity are fixed effects with an interaction. Site is a random factor with 4 levels. Time is a random factor with six levels. Thus:

Proximity = Pro

Reserve = Res

Pro x Res

Site(Pro x Res) = Site(Pro x Res)

Time x Pro

Time x Res

Time x Pro x Res

Time x Site(Pro x Res)

Residuals"

End Quote

So it would seem the reviewer would like  Site (a random factor) to be nested within the interaction of Proximity and Reserve. But they don't seem to want Time nested within Site

I am trying to use the function'lmer' but can't figure out how to nest a random effect within a fixed effect (or two fixed effects in this case). Is this even possible/necessary? And should Time be nested within Site?

My code so far is

```
anova(lmer(Abundance ~ Reserve*Proximity+(1|Site)+(1|Time), data=env_subset))
```

or

```
anova(lmer(Abundance ~ Reserve*Proximity/(1|Site/Time), data=env_subset))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Were sites chosen randomly or on purpose?

Comment: Sites were selected randomly